# Create delegate method for location status change event for windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, location

I am currently working with windows phone 8.1 [RT] application , I am using GeoLocation for map service , I want event that occur whenever device location is on/off , same as `NetworkStatusChangedEventHandler` for internet connection .
I have create following code for that

```
 public static bool IsLocationOn
 {
        get
        {
            Geolocator locator = new Geolocator();

            if (locator.LocationStatus == PositionStatus.Disabled)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }

        }
 }
```

but I want event that fire on entire application 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Geolocator has a [`StatusChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator.statuschanged) event. From there, it's just a matter of subscribing to it.

```
locator.StatusChanged += Geolocator_StatusChanged;

private void Geolocator_StatusChanged(Geolocator locator, StatusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Whatever
}
```